# Firebase hosting : Detect social media crawler bots like facebook, twitter and google

Tags: node.js, facebook, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have firebase hosting setup currently redirecting to index.html like this.

```js
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/details/**",
        "function": "details"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want to redirect the request based on user-agents like Facebot for Facebook ...

Is there a way to redirect request on firebase hosting before reaching on cloud function? 
I know it's possible inside the function but I would love to do it on the hosting configuration.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question as well

Comment: Detect the user agent and if you find it to match the bot redirect to your servers meta tag configured html.

Comment: @dshukertjr me too!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this by creating a cloud function that redirects the bot request.
You can identify the bot using the request's user agent.